# Mysql query; get all threads that have all of given users

Tags: mysql

Database's schema:

A `user` can participate in multiple threads, and a `thread` may have multiple users(many-to-many relationship).

**Input:** An array of `user_id's` (1,2,3,4...).

**Output:** Get all the threads(`thread_id's`) that all given users have participated in(in each thread there must be all given users).

```
mysql> describe participants;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| thread_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_read  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is table's schema:

Can anyone help me please with a `mysql` query to get results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get threads based on your criteria by doing aggregation

```
select p.thread_id
from participants p
where p.user_id in(1,2,3,4)
group by p.thread_id
having count(distinct p.user_id) = @count_of_ your_ids /* like 4 */
```

Comment: What is count for?

Comment: @ako you need to put the count to user ids which you will provide in `IN()` clause like if your array will have 3 user ids then put 3 there

Comment: It throws error : `Unknown column 'p' in 'field list'`.

Comment: It has no error now, but result is not correct. Can we discuss about it [here in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166616/aspire-me)?